# Popup message before login windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find a way in powershell to create a popup message that will occur after startup, but before user login. I want to write a script that will check a log file, see if an error was logged, and create the popup if so

Comment: You will probably need to run the script as NT AUTHORITY\System to do this. Your best bet will probably be to create a scheduled task to run at startup under the system account. **Disclaimer:** I have not tested this, and am not 100% sure it will work, thus it being a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Please update your question with how you are checking for the logged error and what you have tried so far. I would agree with @Jesse . Create a scheduled task and use something like `[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Error was logged')`

Comment: For security reasons, I don't think there is an easy way to interact with the user prior login (without breaking/rewriting the [GINA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-and-gina)) but as a workaround you might be able to use the LegalNoticeCaption and LegalNoticeText (registry keys).

Answer (score 1):

You used to be able to do this on Windows XP/2003 by displaying a dialog box from a process running as the `SYSTEM` user, but with the advent of Vista this is no longer possible (there was a registry key you could set to restore the behavior but Microsoft neutered it in Windows 7+). However, you can display messages on the login screen before login by editing the local security policy (or editing the security policy via GPO).

The policy you want to set is `Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on`.

---

However, this is not as dynamic as you want, and you would not be able to invoke this with a script. [But this policy setting sets a specific registry key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310430/how-to-configure-windows-server-2003-to-display-a-message-when-users-l), which you would be able to set programmatically:

```
# Set 'LegalNoticeCaption' and 'LegalNoticeText' under this key
# LegalNoticeCaption is the "title" of the message
# LegalNoticeText is the full body message you want to convey before login
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

However, there's not an easy way to dismiss this once viewed, and if your organization already uses these keys for general/legal notices on login you will probably get some flak from your IT department for changing this without approval.